# how to attach image file dynamically as background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an input page with multiple submit button for that images .

```
var prop = ['${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/acquirer_aktia.png', '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/acquirer_aktia.png', '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/acquirer_aktia.png', '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/acquirer_aktia.png'];
for (var j = 0; j < prop.length; j++) {
    divElem = $("<div class='row'>");
    $('#bankList').append(divElem);
    elem = $("<div class='col-sm-3'>");
    bankId = $('<input type="submit" >');
    bankId.css('background-image', imagefile);
    elem.prepend(bankId);
    divElem.prepend(elem);
}
```

How to attach url image

Comment: You need `\`...\`` instead of `'...'` to use `${...}`. And the CSS property needs to be `url(.../images/acquirer_aktia.png)`, not just the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the snippet you need to use `url` to have image URL in the background.

```js
var prop = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXM2T.jpg', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYoV8.jpg', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMqex.jpg'];
for (var j = 0; j < prop.length; j++) {
    divElem = $("<div class='row'>");
    $('#bankList').append(divElem);
    elem = $("<div class='col-sm-3'>");
    bankId = $('<input type="submit" >');
    bankId.css('background', 'url('+prop[j]+')');
    elem.prepend(bankId);
    divElem.prepend(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id='bankList'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just use that "prop[j]" value on your loop. which fetch your images url from the array and set for each image.
just replace your loop's "bankId.css" properties.
Thank you.

```
 bankId.css('background-image',prop[j]);
```

Comment: it should be `background: url('...');`

Comment: yes...that would be.
I've just followed the same patter as provided code.
That's why added just that code...
the full code will like that,

`bankId.css('background', 'url('+prop[j]+')');`